# How do I fix this Random Generator? c++

Tags: visual-c++

I am a new programmer and I am working on a school project for c++. So far in my program this is the only thing I am having trouble with. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Now because I'm new and it's for a programming class I'm only in basic c++ next term is intermediate c++ so please keep it simple terms. Thank you!! :)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <iomanip>  
using namespace std;  

int srand (time(0)); 
static int question = rand % 3;
```

my 'rand' is what has a red sqiuggley which says 'expression must have integral or enum type'

this is what the error says when I compile the program:
 1>o:\cs101 and cs106\movie game\movie game\movie title.h(10): error C2365: 'srand' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'

The goal I am trying to accomplish is to pick a random question in each of my functions (there are five functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand` here is a function.

You can call it like this `rand()` (so your whole like would be `static int question = rand() % 3;`.

See this page on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) for more examples of how to use this function. (By the way, that website is a great reference for the standard library, keep it bookmarked!)